# Protecting a file against the upgrade. OK to make immutable?

Tags: apt, upgrade, vim

Running Ubuntu 18.04 on x64.

For one particular package, namely Vim/Gvim, there are a few custom files that I install in one of the directories (specifically, the "syntax" directory).  I have found that when I do the usual update/upgrade thing, and a new version of the package gets installed, it over-writes my custom file.

Took me a while to figure out why my syntax highlighting was no longer working as before.  Would (obviously) like to take some steps to make sure this doesn't happen again the next time the package is upgraded.

Seems to me to boil down to 3 possibilities:

1. Make the file in question immutable (with chattr).  This is the first thing I thought of and is, alas, brute force, but the question then becomes: Would this cause the upgrade process to get confused and space out?  (Note; This is the question I really want to hear from the community about)
2. Is there some way in the apt/apt-get/etc ecosystem to mark a file as not-to-be-changed?  Not a whole package, mind you (I know how to do that with apt-mark), but just one single file.
3. Given that we're talking about Vim, I think it is actually possible to put local versions of the syntax files in your home directory, under ~/.vim - but the details escape me at the moment and I'd rather not do it this way if possible.

Comment: Look up how to `apt-mark` or `apt-pin` to prevent a package upgrade.

Comment: You could make a backup and restore from backup any files that changed that you didn't want to change.

Comment: It is not about preventing a package upgrade.  I mentioned apt-mark in the OP and explained why it isn't what I want.  I want the usual upgrade to take place; I just don't want it to touch one (or a few) specific file(s).

Comment: Of course there are backups, but it is pain to have to remember this.  Really, I want to make the file immutable; I just want to be re-assured that it won't cause Ubuntu to blow a gasket in frustration...

Comment: That's *why* you make a backup. Do what you want and if it "blows a gasket" you can replace it with the backup

Comment: The point is not the backup.  The point is: Will the OS do something stupid (like reformatting the hard disk) if it can't over-write the file?  Will it hang for hours, trying repeatedly to write a file that will never work?  Will it abort the restore or corrupt the APT database(s)?  You have to admit, there are lots of possibilities.  These are the sorts of things you'd rather get a definitive answer to, rather than just go ahead and determine emperically.